# Control a plant with a general logistic function like characteristic

Tags: nonlinear-control

I have a "real" plant, which is basically a light bulb, with a characteristic curve which matches the shape of a [generalised logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_logistic_function)

I need to control that plant dynamically over it's complete range. I only have very basic knowledge about control so I don't know if it is advisable to linearize the characterstic for different setpoint ranges or if it is more feasable to identify a nonlinear model using wikipedia's differential equation.

What are your thoughts about expected complexity going the nonlinear model way?

Comment: "*...using wikipedia's differential equation*". What does this mean? Where does the concept of differential equation come from? Your light bulb's characteristic curve is probably and algebraic equation and not a differential equation ?

Comment: I refered to Generalised logistic differential equation in the wikipedia article. From my understanding one could construct a transfer function from wikipedias differential equation.